# Asus laptop just turn on when charging

Tags: battery, power

Last day my laptop charge was 5% and it's turn off automatic. after that my laptop not charging more then 87% and it's show *plugged in, charging*
I try Press power button for 20 sec , but after that problem does not fix and I can turn on laptop just when plugged in
Model : n552vw

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running a battery report to check what the health information of the battery is, and to see how the capacity has decreased during the course of owning the laptop?

If not you can run either this command in PowerShell (Windows 8 or 10):

```
powercfg /batteryreport
```

Or you can run this in the command prompt (Windows 7):

```
cd %userprofile%\desktop
powercfg -energy
```

These commands will generate a health report on the battery to your desktop or whichever directory you specify.

According to the ASUS Website, their batteries have a lifespan between 300 to 500 charge cycles.

[ASUS Battery Information Centre](https://www.asus.com/support/article/604/)

In some cases (I know this with Dell but unsure on ASUS) you can also check the BIOS which will specify a very basic detail of the health of the battery.

It might also be worth trying another charger in the device (that is compatible with your laptop). If the charger is faulty, it may be the cause as to why the battery isn't charging properly. It seems unlikely as you're only able to turn the device on with it plugged in, but without more information regarding the battery health it's a possibility.

Could you let us know if you've tried any diagnostic work or fixes? That way other answers and comments won't repeat work that you may have already tried :)

Comment: The requirement to have a little reputation before being able to comment is not an invitation to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's very useful information.  And Mohammed, I had a similar-sounding problem with a brand new Asus laptop. It would run while plugged in but the battery never charged enough.  The vendor immediately replaced the laptop with a new one. If yours is still under warranty, you might want to see if they'll replace or repair it.

Comment: my battery report: [link](https://ufile.io/8rst7)

Comment: also I press power button for 30 second like this [link](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?82461-ASUS-G751-CH71-Battery-stuck-at-84&viewfull=1#post569255)  and after that laptop work just when plugged in

Comment: @Blackwood True, but given that this isn't technically a fix for his issue it might not be construed as an answer which is why I thought a comment was more appropriate. Either way it's still valid advice.

Comment: @MohammadHossein Have you tried updating your Windows to the highest patch level possible? Also, try updating the BIOS to the newest version you can. I've had issues with batteries (Not ASUS tbh) which updating the BIOS resolved. Give those a go and let us know how you get on?